# Is there any way to view GUI in Enterprise Architect that was imported from Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, import, enterprise-architect

As it happened, I have to develop several GUI forms in both Visual Studio 2019 and Enterprise Architect for my university studies.
I found out a way to import Visual Studio 2019 project into Enterprise Architect 15.0, but I cannot see it as graphical forms - the way I can see it in Visual Studio's Form Design window. I mean buttons, checkboxes, etc, not the source code. Now I can see only the source code in Enterprise Architect.

That is what I see in Enterprise Architect Browser
[image: That is what I see in Enterprise Architect Browser]

This is what I see in VS, but can't find a way to do the same in Enterprise Architect
[image: This is what I see in VS, but can't find a way to do the same in Enterprise Architect]

Is there any way to switch the view?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.1/model_domains/win32_ui_import_one.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically no. EA is no forms design tool but an UML modeling tool. There are UI profiles

[image]

you could use to do UI sketches. EA won't create that from a code import. You could use these profiles but I doubt it will be useful. Stick with your VS to model the GUI.